# Getting syntax error, unexpected 'App' (T_STRING)

Tags: laravel-5

Just created new laravel (5.4) project , uploaded into shared hosting

showing following error

```
 (1/1) FatalErrorException

syntax error, unexpected 'App' (T_STRING)
in HomeController.php (line 1)
```

what is the reason behind this , why it is showing error in word App , i thinks its default namespace name right? , working fine in local (WIN 10 , XAMPP )

Please help!

Code of HomeController.php is very huge...still posting first few lines

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Coupon;
use App\Footer;
use App\Home;
use App\Http\Models;
use App\Merchant;
use App\Register;
use App\Settings;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use MyPayPal;
use Session;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Home Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish to use controllers instead of, or in addition to, Closure
    | based routes. That's great! Here is an example controller method to
    | get you started. To route to this controller, just add the route:
    |
    |   Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
    |
    */
    public function siteadmin()
    {
        return Redirect::to('siteadmin');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $city_details = Register::getCityDetails();
        $header_category = Home::getHeaderCategory();
        $product_details = Home::getProductDetails();
        $women_product = Home::getWomenProduct();
        $most_visited_product = Home::getMostVisitedProduct();
        $deals_details = Home::getDealsDetails();
        $auction_details = Home::getAuctionDetails();
        $get_product_details_by_cat = Home::getProductDetailsByCategory($header_category);
        $category_count = Home::getCategoryCount($header_category);
        $get_product_details_typeahed = Home::getProductDetailsTypeahed();
        $main_category = Home::getHeaderCategory();
        $sub_main_category = Home::getSubMainCategory($main_category);
        $second_main_category = Home::getSecondMainCategory($main_category, $sub_main_category);
        $second_sub_main_category = Home::getSecondSubMainCategory();
        $get_social_media_url = Home::getSocialMediaUrl();
        $cms_page_title = Home::getCmsPageTitle();
        $country_details = Register::getCountryDetails();
        $addetails = Home::getAdDetails();
        $noimagedetails = Home::getNoimageDetails();
        $getbannerimagedetails = Home::getbannerimagedetails();
        $getmetadetails = Home::getmetadetails();
        $getlogodetails = Home::getlogodetails();
        $get_contact_det = Footer::getContactDetails();
        $getanl = Settings::social_media_settings();
        $general = Home::getGeneralSettings();
        if (Session::has('customerid')) {
            $navbar = view('includes.loginnavbar')->with('country_details', $country_details)->with('metadetails', $getmetadetails)->with('general', $general);
        } else {
            $navbar = view('includes.navbar')->with('country_details', $country_details)->with('metadetails', $getmetadetails)->with('general', $general);
        }
        $header = view('includes.header')->with('header_category', $header_category)->with('logodetails', $getlogodetails);
        $footer = view('includes.footer')->with('cms_page_title', $cms_page_title)->with('get_social_media_url', $get_social_media_url)->with('get_contact_det', $get_contact_det)->with('getanl', $getanl);
        return view('index')->with('navbar', $navbar)->with('header', $header)->with('footer', $footer)->with('header_category', $header_category)->with('product_details', $product_details)->with('deals_details', $deals_details)->with('auction_details', $auction_details)->with('get_product_details_by_cat', $get_product_details_by_cat)->with('most_visited_product', $most_visited_product)->with('category_count', $category_count)->with('get_product_details_typeahed', $get_product_details_typeahed)->with('main_category', $main_category)->with('sub_main_category', $sub_main_category)->with('second_main_category', $second_main_category)->with('second_sub_main_category', $second_sub_main_category)->with('addetails', $addetails)->with('noimagedetails', $noimagedetails)->with('bannerimagedetails', $getbannerimagedetails)->with('metadetails', $getmetadetails)->with('women_product', $women_product)->with('get_contact_det', $get_contact_det)->with('general', $general);
    }
```

Comment: show code of `HomeController.php`

Comment: @MaitraySuthar : updated qustion with code , although code of HomeController.php is very big, posted first few functions...

Comment: have you included starting php tag `<?php` before the `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` ?

Comment: Yupp starting <?php is there

Comment: May be its spacing problem between `<?php` and `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`. (T_STRING) error comes when no white space is there between php start tag and variable/function.

Comment: its most likely you forgot to a curly brace somewhere so your class cant be closed. check all curly braces try to dd() in the first line of your function.